# Why does localhost work but my alias does not?

Tags: wordpress, apache2, virtualhost

I currently have this apache2 site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName engine.com
    ServerAlias www.engine.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/engine.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I type engine.com I just get a blank page.

My directory setup is like this

```
/var/www/engine.com/public_html/wp-content...
```

Localhost works fine and wordpress installation is triggered, but as I say engine.com just brings me a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to add

> engine.com 127.0.0.1

to your hosts file?